# Are references to mapped values of node handles valid?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap

I know references to elements of `value_type` inside C++ maps are unusable while they are owned by a node handle.

My question is, are references to mapped values also unusable while the element is owned by a node handle?

See code below for illustration:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, std::string> map{{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"}};

    auto iter = map.find(1);            // (1)
    auto& ref_ele = *iter;              // (2)
    auto& ref_mapped = iter->second;    // (3)

    auto nh = map.extract(1);

    // (1): Invalid
    // (2): Unusable
    // (3): Unusable?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `extract()` doesn't move objects, the `ref_mapped` is equivalent to `nh.mapped()`. So I think `ref_mapped` can be safely used until the node is destroyed or moved somewhere.

Comment: @dalfaB `extract` does implementation-defined magic, so you can't say that